# An unknown exception occured while executing a sandbox code

Tags: sandbox-solution

Just created a visual webpart as sandbox solution, didn't changed a word other then adding some text to visual webpart, tried to deploy it but getting this exception,

[image]

it is a single server with dc, sql and everything on it (SP 2013)

An attempt to connect to the remote activator failed with exception '

Comment: Did you find the ULS log entries about this error.
Sandbox Solutions are launched through the process of SPUCWorkerProcess.exe ([MSDN sandbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798382.aspx)).

Comment: Did you use Visual Webpart(Sandbox) or normal visual webpart.Normal visual webpart will not work in sandbox solutions.

Comment: i also tried with webpart, same exception

Answer (score 3):

Strangely enough, this fixes the problem for me on SharePoint 2013 instance installed on a Windows Domain Controller:

Set-SPLogLevel -Identity "SharePoint Foundation:Sandboxed Code Service" -TraceSeverity "Verbose"

Restart-Service -Name "SharePoint User Code Host"

Of course, I only use this in a non-production environment.

Comment: This helped me - I'm not sure why, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run sandboxed code on a single server installation of SharePoint 2013 on Windows Server 2012 + domain controller. You can install and activate the solution without any problems, but any sandboxed code will throw the following error:

> An unknown exception occurred while executing a sandboxed code
>   solution request in the worker process.

Reference: http://www.jrjlee.com/2013/04/another-reason-to-stop-developing.html
Check the comments of the link, there seems to be a workaround, I would not recommended it.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a visual webpart, the ascx control file needs to be deployed to the physical path in controltemplates folder. However, sandboxed solutions cannot deploy the files to the physical path. This is one of the restrictions in Sandbox solutions.

Comment: i also tried with webpart, same exception

Comment: Is User code host service running?

Comment: yes it is running very fast

Comment: pls tell me what speed it is running?